# numpy dot product but keep as vector (not add elements up)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want something like the following:

```
a = b 'dot' c x h'
```

where

```
a is 10 by 201

b = 10 by 1

c = 10 by 1

h is 1 by 201
```

However, when I say b 'dot' c, I don't actually want to sum everything up to get a scalar  -I want a 10 by 1 vector as the result.

I don't know what this actually is.

np.dot(b, c) doesn't work because it computes the dot product scalar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a = b * c * h` should work. It's an example of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I definitely didn't know there was such a thing.